# What is the idiomatic way to compute values based on neighboring values, in NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I am asked to experiment with numpy calculating values in a two-dimensinal array/matrix (rows, columns) where these values depend on neighboring values. This is not just multiplying the matrix with a scalar or anything like that, even though it may be reduced to a series of such steps, I admit.

Even though this is homework, my question is broader in scope than just asking for a solution handed to me.

I have read up on broadcasting, i.e. vectorization, in numpy, and I could imagine one way would be implementing this as a new *ufunc* and running it on the matrix. However, I am a bit wary of limitations I may face - can a numpy *ufunc* access a neighboring element, versus the one it computes during current iteration? Conceptually:

```
for x in columns:
    for y in rows:
        a[x, y] = a[x, y - 1] + a[x, y + 1] + a[x - 1, y] + a[x + 1, y] + A + B + b[x, y] # '+' is just an example of a binary op here.
```

meaning that the value in each cell depends on neighboring cells and also some constants and even values in another matrix.

Reading numpy documentation hasn't helped me all that much. What would be the preferred/idiomatic way to do this in numpy?

Comment: The person voting to close this, please provide rationale, otherwise I have no clue what is wrong and there is a big chance my next question in similar style will also attact close-votes, and so on.

Comment: the only thing I can find "bad" about this question is the overly exhaustive prose you write – my recommendation would be to try to reduce on all the "problem-irrelevant" facts you mention, but then again, I'm totally in favor of people mentioning the goal and background. Your text simply was a little *too repetitive*, but not *too broad*, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is very common in image processing -- there it's called *applying a kernel to do two-dimensional filtering* (just to give you something to google). From the [Numpy ndimage documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/ndimage.html#filter-functions):

> The functions described in this section all perform some type of
>   spatial filtering of the input array: the elements in the output are
>   some function of the values in the neighborhood of the corresponding
>   input element. We refer to this neighborhood of elements as the filter
>   kernel, which is often rectangular in shape but may also have an
>   arbitrary footprint. Many of the functions described below allow you
>   to define the footprint of the kernel, by passing a mask through the
>   footprint parameter. For example a cross shaped kernel can be defined
>   as follows:
>
> ```
> footprint = array([[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0]])
> footprint array([[0, 1, 0],
>                  [1, 1, 1],
>                  [0, 1, 0]])
> ```

What you'd then do is use the [`convolve` function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html):

```
from scipy import ndimage
output = ndimage.convolve(matrix, footprint)
```

If you want "wrapping" behaviour like [xnx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33234569/4433386) has, use the `mode="wrap"` argument to `convolve`:

```
output = ndimage.convolve(matrix, footprint, mode="wrap")
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure I can use `scipy`, moreover I don't even have it installed. I do have `numpy`. Is it possible to do the convolution and applying a kernel without SciPy? I have checked and there is a `convolve()` available in `numpy`. It seems that the relationship between `scipy` and `numpy` is not very clearly defined, either.

Answer (score 2):

Slicing your array appropriately may help you in simple cases. For example to add neighbouring columns and rows in an array `a` to an output array, `B`:

```
In [5]: B = a.copy()
In [6]: B[1:,:] += a[:-1,:]
In [7]: B[:-1,:] += a[1:,:]
In [8]: B[:,1:] += a[:,:-1]
In [9]: B[:,:-1] += a[:,1:]
```

(This doesn't give quite the same result as the `convolve` approach suggested in the other answer because it handles the edges of the array differently.)

Comment: edited my answer; `mode="wrap"` does exactly that :)